# Brushed metal material: not straight

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

New to Blender, and my first question on Stack Exchange.

I'm trying to create a brushed metal effect on a ring. However, my brushed effect is appearing in a circular shape, rather than in straight lines around the ring as I would like.

Images show the effect I'm getting, and the shader setup I'm using.
[image: Brushed metal effect is appearing in circular sweeps, and not straight lines]
[image: Shader setup for brushed metal material]

How can I make the brushed effect appear in straight lines around the circumference of the object?

Comment: Then you need to scale it on the vertical axis, which is Z. Try changing Y back to scale 1 and Z to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the *Mapping > Scale* on Z:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was an easy fix in the end.