# How can I create a procedural die cast aluminium shader similar to these photos?

Tags: shader-nodes

I want to recreate the die cast alumunium material you can see in the reference images.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where exacly are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve the line effect seen in the reference image.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/302488/78972

Comment: Thanks, buddy, it was greatly helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Try a mix between a *Noise Texture* that is stretched on Z and another one that is not, through a *Color > Mix Color* in *Multiply* mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, buddy, it was greatly helpful.